# Maven Sonar Plugin that generates HTML

Tags: maven, sonarqube

Possibly a ridiculous question. But I'm a total noob with maven and sonar...

I'm using the sonar plugin for maven. It works great.
Using the command "mvn sonar:sonar" it connects to my localhost and I can view everything on port 9000.

What I'm wondering is:
Is it possible to generate all the files (eg. html, css, etc) without connecting to the server at port 9000?

If so, is there a command to do it?

If not :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. Sonar is designed to have a server with a database and a client pulling the configs from the server and writing the results back to sonar.

If you want a solution without the sonar server you need to configure the maven findbugs plugin, cobertura, pmd and so on by your own and include there output in the maven site.

How this is done for findbugs is explained here:
[How to generate a html report for findbugs with Maven 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564208/how-to-generate-a-html-report-for-findbugs-with-maven-3-x)

Comment: :( Thanks for putting me out of my misery. And thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Comment: Indeed there's no full HTML export, but you can give a try to the Issue Report Plugin. It generates a HTML report of violations but not of metrics.
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin