# How can I set up FindBugs in my Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I want to set FindBugs in my maven project so I can know how may errors and bugs I have.

1. I want to know how to set the FindBugs in a Maven project.
2. How can I get a report? Where can I find it?

I'm using IntelliJ id on Ubuntu.

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try googling "findbugs maven"? Because the first match I found led me to the FindBugs Maven Plugin which has explicit instructions. Voting to close.

Comment: i did after doing setting report is not generating

Comment: Then add your pom here...

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564208/how-to-generate-a-html-report-for-findbugs-with-maven-3-x?rq=1

Comment: Now its done thnks @slim