# Maven execute a goal on build fail / FindBugs

Tags: maven, maven-3, findbugs

I have integrated FindBugs plugin to fail the build in case of bugs.
Then using that [brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365954/5151575) I configured FindBugs to generate html reports (xml version is barely readable).
The problem is that I have `failOnError` property set to `true`, which means that the build would fail in case of bug.

```
 .....
 <configuration>
        .....
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
 </configuration>
```

And then no html report would be generated.

I read about [Maven build lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17123957/5151575) and there is no such thing as "Execute on fail" (like `finally` block in Java). So, are there any possible workarounds?
And shouldn't it be out-of the box Maven feature?

Comment: The HTML report is generated by the plugin which means if the plugin find a bug it fails. So if you like having the plugin generating a html report independent of failing you should file in an issue for the plugin https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess in this case it's easier to request html report generation instead of xml one. Anyway it sounds like time-consuming solution.

Comment: How about using multiple runs of the findbugs plugin? In an early build phase run the plugin to generate the report. In a later run the plugin with `failOnError` set to `true`. This will slow down the build for the moment, but you would have an option to wait for a better solution.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker thank you for suggestion. I'll give it a try.
Anyway submitted [request](https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/issues/44) for that feature.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker yeah, your solution works, thank you again! And total build time growth is not that critical. So, why not to post it as an answer?)

Comment: @Enigo Thanks for the feedback. But I think you can already post a better answer than me since you can easily include the pom snippets required for the solution to work. I would have to create them. You should probably refer to my comment in your answer for attribution rules to be followed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special thanks to **@SpaceTrucker** for workaround [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632682/maven-execute-a-goal-on-build-fail-findbugs#comment64654907_38632682).
Here is the configuration I ended up with:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4</version>
   <configuration>
       <effort>Max</effort>
       <threshold>Low</threshold>
       <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>noFailOnError</id>
           <phase>verify</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <failOnError>false</failOnError>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
           <id>failOnError</id>
           <phase>install</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <failOnError>true</failOnError>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

The solution is to use different configurations in `verify` and `install` phases.
Note, that according to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365954/5151575) transformation (to html) is executed in `verify`phase.

*Issue was [submitted](https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/issues/44) for html report generation.*

Results are also can be seen by simply run `mvn findbugs:gui`